# Will SharePoint apply the same source permission setting for the items displayed through the “Content Query” web part

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, permissions, content-query-web-part

I have a team site collection inside SharePoint server 2013. the site collection have 10 sub sites. now I want to display subsites' items that match certain criteria inside the site collection welcome page.

So I find that the Content Query web part can achieve what I am looking for. But I need to know how the permission will be applied to the items inside the Content Query web part in the following scenario:-

In my case each of the subsites has different permission on who can view/edit the items. so let say userA do not have a permission to view items inside Subsite1 ,, so if I am showing items from subsite1 inside the content query web part,, so in this case will userA be able to see subsite1’s items inside the content query web part, since he have permission to view the site collection home page (where the content query web part is added)? Or SharePoint will apply the same permission for these items as they are defined inside subsite1, so in this case userA will not see any items from subsite1 but he will view items from the subsites he have permission on them ?

Thanks

Comment: yes it will respect permissions

Comment: @EricAlexander yes u are correct ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes it will respect the source permissions

Comment: Please provide more information.